# Excel - Total for range of values accounting for changing annual inflation rate

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a series of values for previous years along with the inflation rate for that year:

[image: Data]

With the above data the formula for the first entry in the Cumulative column would be:

```
A2*(1+B2)
```

For a given range of years (in this example, this period of 10 years) I need to produce a formula which adjusts first entry (A2) for inflation (A3), adds to the second entry (A3) and then adjusts that figure for inflation for its corresponding year (B3) - and so on.
e.g. Cell C3 would contain

```
(C2 + A3)*(1+B3)
```

The figure I'm really interested in is the overall value of this range of values in column A for this period of 10 years, adjusted for cumulative inflation, as I need to look up from this table (which has about 40 years of data) varying 10 year periods using VLOOKUP e.g I could need the values for the orange range or the yellow range, not affected by any previous or following values.

Comment: What's wrong with copying the formula you described for C3 down the column and then summing C?

Comment: Because I need to look up various periods in the table - this sample is only 10 years, but I have 40 years of data and I could need the total value for years 26 to 36 i.e. the starting value would be A26, then calculate cumulative inflation from that point onwards but only for values of A26-A36, not previous values before A26

Comment: Edited the question to clarify the above

Comment: How will the formulas know the start and end points of the range?  Will you enter row or cell references in input cells?  Will it always be 10 years, so you can derive the end point from the start point?  Is there another column not shown with some form of date ID and you will enter those dates and look up the rows?

Comment: Yes, each row is dated. I'm using VLOOKUP to get the data range using the dates

Comment: Can you add the detail of that to the question?  Any solution will need to incorporate how you're doing that.

Comment: The formula at https://powerpivotpro.com/2013/11/cumulative-interest-or-inflation-multiplying-every-value-in-a-column-why-dont-we-have-productx/ is exactly what I need, if anyone knows how to convert to Excel